# What's the minimum forestal mass required to generate land wildlife?

Tags: the-settlers-2

What's the minimum forestal mass required to generate land wildlife? I don't think a single tree can generate land wildlife.

Is it enough with seven contiguous trees? Seven like, in this picture, a contiguous mass:

```
  o   o

o   o   o

  o   o
```

---

Also, what would be the necessary forestal mass required to bring a single hunter hut to 100% productivity without generating any excess wildlife? In this case, I understand this depends on the forestal mass's exact form and the distance to the hunter hut, but I find it interesting if only approximate or intuitive answers are given.

Comment: "All the programmers who really knew are now dead" is a valid answer (if that's the truth).

Comment: Would experimental evidence count as a reputable source here? The expansion did come with a map editor.

Comment: Please don't. Once the bounty is expired and there's no rush, anything you do is welcome.

Comment: If you'd be so kind to go out there and get me some [Blue Byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Byte_Software) developer here answering this question good, I'd be awarding them a 250 rep bounty. This offer does not expire. Cheers.

Comment: And no I will absolutely not award any bounty on experimental evidence (which would smaller, be say 100 rep instead) unless I have any authoritative reference that one can actually award multiple bounties to multiple answers in the same question.

Comment: Ok then. Good luck.